# Cant update Freya 64 bit

Tags: updates

Since Loki was released i have problems updating Freya....I get:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you usin a x86 or x86-64? From Loki and on, x86 architectures are no more supported. I think you should always use only eOS main repository, not any other one for system updates/upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you messed up your main repository source list `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you'll have to fix it manually.

Open Scratch with administrator privileges:

```
pkexec scratch-text-editor
```

then open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu freya partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu freya partner
```

to

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Answer (score -2):

Back up your data and make a fresh install.